# how to expand multiple properties when output contains @{<value1=xxx>,<value1=yyy> }?

Tags: powershell, output, select-string, select-object

I know there's a number of posts about expanding a single property and hopefully this is an easy one but my output looks like this as a result of a

```
select-string -simplematch
```

```
@{Brand=Volkswagen; Model=Passat}
@{Brand=Ford; Model=Mondeo}
```

But how do I expand both properties and get the output to look like this please?

> Volkswagen, Passat
> Ford, Mondeo

When I do a `select-object *` I get the below but I cant seem to get just the values

> IgnoreCase : True
> Linenumber : 1
> Line : @{Brand=Volkswagen; Model=Passat}
> Filename : InputStream
> Path : InputStream
> Pattern : @{Brand=Volkwagen; Model=Passat}
> Context :
> Match : {}}
>
> IgnoreCase : True
> Linenumber : 2
> Line : @{Brand=Ford; Model=Mondeo}
> Filename : InputStream
> Path : InputStream
> Pattern : @{Brand=Ford; Model=Mondeo}
> Context :
> Match : {}}

Comment: I commend to your attention the [documentation for `Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1), specifically the `-ExpandProperty` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do `select-string` on a collection of PsObjects, because that cmdlet is designed for finding text in **strings** and **files**..
`Select-Object -ExpandProperty` lets you expand **one** property, not all.
If you want output like that, loop over the objects in the array and combine the properties the way you want them into a string.

Assume your array is like this:

```
$theCarCollection = [PsCustomObject]@{Brand='Volkswagen'; Model='Passat'},
                    [PsCustomObject]@{Brand='Ford'; Model='Mondeo'}
```

Then format the output by looping over the objects and selecting the properties you need

```
($theCarCollection | ForEach-Object { '{0}, {1}' -f $_.Brand, $_.Model }) -join [environment]::NewLine
```

which will output:

```
Volkswagen, Passat
Ford, Mondeo
```

Comment: Thanks but I have hundreds of records in two different files which I'm doing the match on so the array will not work as I don't have the ability to make changes to the input files

Comment: @kkp0897 Then explain what these files are.. CSV perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

may be somthing lie this :

```
Select-String -Path "C:\temp\test.txt" -Pattern "test" | select line -ExpandProperty line
```

Comment: Thanks but no that did not work, it just returned the following again

@{Brand=Volkswagen; Model=Passat}
@{Brand=Ford; Model=Mondeo}

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66457449/45375):

**tl;dr**:

```sh
# Note the use of -PipelineVariable obj and the use of $obj later.
PS> Write-Output -PipelineVariable obj (
      [pscustomobject] @{ Brand = 'Volkswagen'; Model = 'Passat' }, 
      [pscustomobject] @{ Brand = 'Ford'; Model = 'Mondeo' }
    ) |
      Select-String -SimpleMatch wagen |
        ForEach-Object { $obj.psobject.Properties.Value -join ', ' }

Volkswagen, Passat
```

The [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) command is just a stand-in for the actual command that produces the input objects for `Select-String` in your code, such as `Import-Csv`.

---

- Your [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) output implies that `[pscustomobject]` instances served as its input, such as output by [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv), for instance.

  - E.g., your output implies an input object such as
    `[pscustomobject] @{ Brand = 'Volkswagen'; Model = 'Passat' }`
- As Theo notes, `Select-String` is designed to operate on *strings*, not on *objects with properties*.

  - When `Select-String` receives such objects, it creates a *string* representation for them and searches *that*.
  - What makes this particularly unhelpful is that this string representation is *not* the same you would see in the *terminal* (console), where PowerShell's rich output formatting is used; instead, simple `.ToString()` stringification is performed, which with `[pscustomobject]` instances results in representations such as `'@{Brand=Volkswagen; Model=Passat}'` (perhaps confusingly, this resembles - but is not the same as - a *hashtable literal*).

    - [GitHub issue #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726) proposes changing `Select-String` to instead operate on the rich display-formatting representations.
- Additionally, if you *do* let `Select-String` operate on such objects, its *output* ([`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances) no longer contain the input *objects*, only *their string representations*, which means that in order to extract the values `Volkswagen` and `Passat`, you'd have to perform *string parsing*, which is both cumbersome and not robust.

---

To filter input objects with properties based on property values, [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) is the better choice; e.g.:

```sh
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ Brand = 'Volkswagen'; Model = 'Passat' }, 
    [pscustomobject] @{ Brand = 'Ford'; Model = 'Mondeo' } |
      Where-Object Brand -eq Volkswagen

Brand      Model
-----      -----
Volkswagen Passat
```

That said, using `Select-Object` can still be helpful *if you don't know what properties the input objects have*, and want to locate a value *somewhere* in the object, via its *string* representation:

```sh
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ Brand = 'Volkswagen'; Model = 'Passat' }, 
    [pscustomobject] @{ Brand = 'Ford'; Model = 'Mondeo' } |
      Select-String -SimpleMatch wagen

@{Brand=Volkswagen; Model=Passat}
```

The above is what you tried, but, as stated, this effectively outputs just the string representation of the entire object, with no (easy) ability to extract property values afterwards.

The solution is to use the [common `-PipelineVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters?view=powershell-7.2#pipelinevariable) on the input-object-producing command, which allows access to the object at hand in a *later* pipeline segment's ([`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)) script block, which allows you to create the desired comma-separated list of property values easily (even without knowing the property names):

```sh
# Note the use of -PipelineVariable obj and the use of $obj later.
PS> Write-Output -PipelineVariable obj (
      [pscustomobject] @{ Brand = 'Volkswagen'; Model = 'Passat' }, 
      [pscustomobject] @{ Brand = 'Ford'; Model = 'Mondeo' }
    ) |
      Select-String -SimpleMatch wagen |
        ForEach-Object { $obj.psobject.Properties.Value -join ', ' }

Volkswagen, Passat
```

`$obj.psobject.Properties.Value` uses the hidden, intrinsic `.psobject` property that PowerShell provides for all objects, which is a rich source of *reflection* and in this case allows easy access to all property values, via [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).